# Assume AWS role from service account in AWS EKS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-eks

Current setup: python application is running as a Docker container in AWS EKS cluster. AWS keys are supplied as secrets in kubernetes cluster so that python code can read, initialise boto3 session and work with S3 bucket.

How I would like to change it: assume role of a serviceaccount under which the Docker container is running in AWS EKS cluster and then initialise boto3 session with this credentials and work with S3 bucket. I don't want to supply AWS keys into each service as I have many of them.

Is there any way to implement desired configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: Use guide over here at AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html.

If you have any issues on it, report it here, we can take a look at that.

Answer (score 7):

This is done by what AWS calls IRSA(IAM Roles for serviceaccount)

Simplified  Kubernetes version 1.12 OIDC JSON web token, Amazon EKS now hosts a public OIDC discovery endpoint per cluster containing the signing keys for the JSON web tokens so external systems, like IAM, can validate and accept the OIDC tokens issued by Kubernetes.

---

AWS guide for this is at: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/

AWS guide at github: https://github.com/aws/amazon-eks-pod-identity-webhook/

---

Steps are mentioned below

1. Get OIDC provider URL: `aws eks describe-cluster --name cluster_name --query "cluster.identity.oidc.issuer" --output text`
2. Create the role with federated identity and get ARN for role

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:oidc-provider/OIDC_PROVIDER"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "OIDC_PROVIDER:sub": "system:serviceaccount:SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAMESPACE:SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Keep in mind, you need to mentioned NAMESPACE over here, ensure you have namespace with name SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAMESPACE.

3. Create service account in kubernetes

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: ARN_OF_ABOVE_IAM_ROLE
```

4. Run a pod using serviceaccount

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME
  ...
```

If all done properly, you will be able to assume the role in your k8s pod. Try running any python script in docker container like,

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('iam') 
response = client.list_users()
for x in response['Users']:
print (x['UserName'])
```

Given the permission to IAM this would list the users in AWS Account.

Reference:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/
- https://github.com/aws/amazon-eks-pod-identity-webhook/

Comment: I think this is missing the other half of the equation:  how do we connect boto3 to the service account inside of a pod?

Comment: @BrianBruggeman did you figure it out?

Comment: @BrianBruggeman you run pod with the `serviceAccount` as mentioned above spec
`serviceAccountName: SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME`. Inside pod now, how you call aws api, they should work fine.