# Resolving AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity

Tags: kubernetes, boto3, amazon-iam, rbac, k8s-serviceaccount

Following [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-pods-iam-role-service-accounts/), I cannot resolve the final fifth step, which fails with:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
command terminated with exit code 254
```

My ultimate goal is to have a boto3 client in a pod in a particular namespace perform EC2 actions. I am thinking my role, RBAC, or arn's I am using are not correct. My manifest is at bottom.

Edit: I am getting the AWS envs within the pod, see image.[image]

My role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::<account_number>:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/<oidc_number>"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/<oidc_number>:sub": "system:serviceaccount:reporting-analytics-services-kafka-tools:",
                    "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/<oidc_number>:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My policy (which is attached to the role, I know it's overkill right now):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:*",
                "sts:*",
                "ec2:describeInstances",
                "ec2:stopInstances",
                "ec2:startInstances",
                "iam:ListRoles"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what my deployment file looks like.

```
---
# Source: kafka-tools-pod/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-pod
  name: test-pod
  namespace: reporting-analytics-services-kafka-tools
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
  selector:
    app: test-pod
---
# Source: kafka-tools-pod/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-pod
  name: test-pod
  namespace: reporting-analytics-services-kafka-tools
spec:
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-pod
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 0
      maxUnavailable: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-pod
      annotations:
        Error: "invalid character '$' looking for beginning of value"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: kafka-tools-pod-service-account
      containers:
        - envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: kafka-tools-pod-env
          image: <somenumber>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/kafka-testing:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: test-pod
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1500m
              memory: 3Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 350m
              memory: 128Mi
---
# Source: kafka-tools-pod/templates/ingress-internal.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: internal-nginx
  name: kafka-tools-pod-internal
  namespace: reporting-analytics-services-kafka-tools
spec:
  rules:
    - host: mycompany.use1.develop.percipio.aws
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: test-pod
                port:
                  number: 8080
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
---
# Source: kafka-tools-pod/templates/verticalpodautoscaler.yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-pod
  name: test-pod
  namespace: reporting-analytics-services-kafka-tools
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: test-pod
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: 'Off'
--- 
apiVersion: v1 
kind: ServiceAccount 
metadata:
  name: kafka-tools-pod-service-account
  namespace: reporting-analytics-services-kafka-tools
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::<myaccount>:role/kafka-nodes-reboot-role
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: kakfa-tools-pod-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
- apiGroups: ["extensions"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: kakfa-tools-pod-role-binding
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kafka-tools-pod-service-account
  namespace: reporting-analytics-services-kafka-tools
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: kakfa-tools-pod-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Also looked at answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337079/how-enable-access-to-aws-sts-assumerole), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62787974/assume-aws-role-from-service-account-in-aws-eks) and used the official guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/associate-service-account-role.html).

Comment: When calling `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity()` from your code, what are the permissions associated with the credentials you are using? For example, if you are using boto3, what IAM User (or other entity) is boto3 using, and what are their permissions? They need to be granted `sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` permission, which _allows_ it to call `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity()`. This is before the above IAM Role is even being used.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I understand what you're saying but by writing Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity" in the role and allowing all sts in the policy and including serviceAccountName in the deployment, I thought I accounted for everything. You're implying i'm not so what am I missing? I called the method in the pod with the sts client and using the kubernetes secret and get permission denied, which I guess is expected at this point

Comment: `system:serviceaccount:reporting-analytics-services-kafka-tools:` - try changing to `system:serviceaccount:reporting-analytics-services-kafka-tools:kafka-tools-pod-service-account`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things helped solve the issue.

1. Add `"sts:AssumeRole"` to the policy.
2. As @jordanm suggests edit the arn to the exact pod.
3. Role and roleBinding were configured incorrectly:

```
--- 
apiVersion: v1 
kind: ServiceAccount 
metadata:
  name: kafka-tools-pod-service-account
  namespace: reporting-analytics-services-kafka-tools
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::<accountnumber>:role/KafkaRebootRole
    eks.amazonaws.com/audience: "sts.amazonaws.com"
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: kafka-role
  namespace: reporting-analytics-services-kafka-tools
rules:
  - apiGroups:
        - ""
        - apps
        - autoscaling
        - batch
        - extensions
        - policy
        - rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    resources:
      - pods
      - componentstatuses
      - configmaps
      - daemonsets
      - deployments
      - events
      - endpoints
      - horizontalpodautoscalers
      - ingress
      - jobs
      - limitranges
      - namespaces
      - nodes
      - pods
      - persistentvolumes
      - persistentvolumeclaims
      - resourcequotas
      - replicasets
      - replicationcontrollers
      - serviceaccounts
      - services
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kafka-rolebinding
  namespace: reporting-analytics-services-kafka-tools 
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: kafka-role
subjects:
- namespace: reporting-analytics-services-kafka-tools 
  kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kafka-tools-pod-service-account
```

After this, running `aws sts get-caller-identity` in the pod or using a boto3 client does everything I need it to.